# What sort of magic is my ISP doing?

Tags: http, isp, http-headers

While trying to setup OpenDNS, and failing to make website filtering actually work, I realized my ISP is doing something nefarious with all HTTP requests. To make a long story short, if there's a `Host:` header, it doesn't matter what IP address I use, the website I get depends on the `Host:` header and nothing else.

It also seems to automatically use HTTP/1.1 even if I specify HTTP/1.0 in the request.

Examples:

#### Connect to `google.com` with `Host: yahoo.com`

```
$ echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: yahoo.com\r\n\r\n" | nc google.com 80
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2012 10:50:13 GMT
Location: http://www.yahoo.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
Age: 0
Server: YTS/1.20.0
Connection: close

$
```

#### Connect to an invalid IP address with `Host: yahoo.com`

```
$ echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: yahoo.com\r\n\r\n" | nc 1.0.0.0 80
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2012 10:51:02 GMT
Location: http://www.yahoo.com/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: private
Age: 0
Server: YTS/1.20.0
Connection: close

$
```

So, what is my ISP doing? And should I complain to them?

Comment: Dark magic, from the realm of the Blackbush Enchanted Header.

Comment: Complain to them if you like, but don't be surprised if they respond i n the manner of Arkell vs Pressdram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ISP is using transparent proxy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy

Comment: Yep, that was it. Against Tom O'Connor's advice, I'll ask the ISP about it and see if it can be turned off for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed the OpenDNS [FAQ](http://www.opendns.com/support/article/111):

> **Is OpenDNS running a proxy?**
>
> Yes, sometimes. OpenDNS runs a simple
>   proxy in certain circumstances. Some Internet browsers and many
>   toolbars intercept requests made from the address bar, which prevents
>   initiation of a proper DNS request. Our proxy ensures that your
>   requests are routed properly when using OpenDNS services.
>
> And, like
>   all OpenDNS services, the proxy is respectful of and works hard to
>   protect your privacy. We do not track the DNS requests that are routed
>   through the proxy. In fact, since so many people use toolbars, the
>   proxy must automatically rotate and delete the logs, and this happens
>   frequently.
>
> OpenDNS does not store or mine any of the data that passes
>   through our proxy. The proxy does nothing malicious – it is designed
>   to ensure OpenDNS services work with all browsers and toolbars.

Comment: Nope, I'm sure it's my ISP. This happens even if I'm not using OpenDNS.

Comment: And just to be sure, when I use OpenDNS, I can confirm that DNS queries to supposedly blocked websites really return OpenDNS's "blocked website" address. But when I request a page from that address, I get the real page instead.